# Bot registrations even with Allow User Registration set to No

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, account

In the User Manager options (joomla 3.2) I have the "Allow User Registration" set to "No", yet I am still getting registrations from bots.

Does anyone have any information about how this can happen and how it can be prevented?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I think the problem was that JFBConnect is installed. I made sure to disable the FB login and no other incidents have occurred since then. – Donna May 20 '14 at 17:22

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried turning it on and then back off to see if the setting just didn't get saved correctly?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a bug. Are you using any components with custom registration processes?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug like at some time in jooma's history that this wasn't possible. This has been happening on every Joomla site I have for years and years. I modified the script to disable registration by bots.

Comment: Are you using a Joomla bridge? I've experienced this problem on Joomla 1.5.23, but I suspect it was due to Jfusion.

Comment: Which extensions are installed on that site?

Comment: go to the url /index.php?option=com_users&view=registration and see if you get through, and tell us your installed extensions

Comment: I went to index.php?option=com_users&view=registration and it shows the login, forgot pwd and forgot username but no registration option.

Comment: Can you provide a list of used componentes? We need more information about this. And update please to the latest possible Joomla Version.

Comment: I think the problem was that JFBConnect is installed.  I made sure to disable the FB login and no other incidents have occurred since then.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like something fishy is going on. You could always enable to reCaptcha plugin installed In Joomla by default.